# Remove "he" from all the Hebrew node URLs

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

All the nodes of my Hebrew site using Drupal 8 have this problem: The URL of all the nodes of my Hebrew site are similar to htts://www.example.com/he/node/1, instead of https://www.example.com/node/1. The difference is that now URLs contain /he/, which I have never added.

It happens even when a node has its language set to *English* or *Not specified*.

What I tried is the following:

1. I changed all nodes written for English speaking audience from *Hebrew* to *English* and I flushed the cache. This didn't help: The URLs still contained */he/*.
2. I thought it could be caused by the *Alternative hreflang* module, but uninstalling it did not resolve the issue, even after flushing the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactive the URL detection method from /admin/config/regional/language/detection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have translations, you should not turn off the URL detection method. Instead, you should change the domain prefix in the language settings for Hebrew to have no domain prefix.